# LXD/LXC install issue with snap

Tags: lxd

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and when I install LXD with `sudo snap install lxd` the install is broken somehow and somewhere.

i.e `lxc list` returns

`Error: Get http://unix.socket/1.0: dial unix /var/lib/lxd/unix.socket: connect: connection refused`

BUT

`/snap/bin/lxc list` works fine.

Can someone crafty with SNAPS help me out here so that I can just use `lxc` instead of `/snap/bin/lxc`